# List of android view transition animations?

Tags: android, animation, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

Is there a list of all the animations that I can use to transition between two views? I.e. zoom, slide, face, etc.

I cannot seem to find a comprehensive list, neither in the SDK nor by searching Google.

In addition, is there any demo app that will show all of them, such that I can evaluate which would look best for a specific use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comprehensive list of animations is not possible to be created. Your imagination is the limit to the number of possible animations.

You can use any combination of the basic animations available(alpha, scale, translate and rotate) to transit between two views. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) might help you.

Comment: So there are absolutely no animations available without specifying something custom?

Answer (score 1):

There are many options make animation between views some of are the basic one like alpha, scale, translate and rotate also there new this introduced in the material design concept for view transitions

here you can find sample code the material design git reference for view animation
https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

You can also apply other animation using anim resource

here is activity code you have to write

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {

                 /* Create an intent that will start the main activity. */
                 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                         ConnectedActivity.class);
                 mainIntent.putExtra("id", "1");

                 //SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                 startActivity(mainIntent);
                 /* Finish splash activity so user cant go back to it. */
                 SplashScreen.this.finish();

                 /* Apply our splash exit (fade out) and main
                    entry (fade in) animation transitions. */
                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.mainfadein,R.anim.splashfadeout);
         }
 }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_TIME);   
}
```

Add this two file in res/anim folder.

slide_in.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <translate 
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
              android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
              android:toXDelta="0%p">
        </translate>
```

slide_out.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <translate
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
             android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
             android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
             android:toXDelta="-100%p">
      </translate>
```

I hope this will be solve your queries

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official documentation for the basic animations which you can use in XML files:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html