# Transition Effects while Switching Views

Tags: android

I want to switch views by adding a transition effects for Android (No slide transition).
I found the perfect code for IPhone but not for Android.
Can anyone help me with that please?

Here is the link:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rgnt3auoNw0

Comment: Give it a try yourself and post your code and your problem so that people can help.

Comment: Here is a similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169927/list-of-android-view-transition-animations

Comment: A video tutorial to iPhone code isn't really relevant to an Android question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way like iOS to do view transition in Android. However, it is possible to do so with more code in Android. You can refer to [Transition3d example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Transition3d.html) in Android SDK.

Basically you need to start the first half of animation on the view container, make the replaced view invisible and new view visible, and start the second half animation.